# get records that doesnt exists in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temp table over a 1000 rows but for example purposes as follows

#Table

```
ID    |  Code
33641 | 421230
33642 | 421230
33623 | 200585489
33623 | 45109
```

and then i have another table as follows (this is not a temp table)
Compliance Table

```
ID    |  Code
33623 | 421230
33627 | 421230
33637 | 421230
33641 | 200585489
33642 | 200585489
33623 | 45109
```

how do i check if the records from the temp table doesnt exists in the Compliance table per its ID and Code

so from the above data i would want the following out put

Items that dont match:
output table

```
Id    | Code
33641 | 421230  //doesnt exists
33642 | 421230  //doesnt exists
33623 | 200585489  //doesnt exists
```

from the 4 records in the #temp table 3 of the above records dont exists in the compliance table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from #table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from compliance c
                  where c.id = t.id and c.code = t.code
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use left outer join, like this:

```
select t1.* left outer join t2 on t1.id = t2.id where t2.id is null
```